# SQL DB2 : How to JOIN dynamicaly 2 tables using "running total calculations"

Tags: sql, db2-400

I am learning SQL on a server: IBM V7R1M0, DB2.

I am trying to build a SQL report.
After seeking a similar example several days, I launch this bottle in the ocean of knowledge...

Context: 
The stores request goods from the warehouse.
Those goods are pick on pallets.
Those pallets will be put on staging lane before to load them in a truck.

Rule1: We want only pallet(s) from one store on a staging lane (We don't want to mix the pallets from different stores)

Rule2: A store will occupy staging lanes which are nearby.

Rule3: Staging lanes are ordered by there ID (with gaps)

Table 1:

```
|-----|-----|-----------------|
| ID  |store|pallet_estimation|
|-----|-----|-----------------|
| 1   | A   | 35              |
| 2   | C   |  2              |
| 3   | B   | 30              |
|-----|-----|-----------------|

SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES (1, 'A', 35), (2, 'C', 2), (3, 'B', 30)
          ) T1(ID, store, pallet_estimation)
```

Table 2 :

```
|---------------|---------------|
|ID_staging_lane|pallet_capacity|
|---------------|---------------|
| 201           | 10            |
| 202           | 10            |
| 204           | 30            |
| 205           | 40            |
| 208           | 30            |
| 210           | 30            |
|---------------|---------------|

SELECT * FROM(
  VALUES (201, 10), (202, 10), (204, 30), (205, 40), (208, 30), (210, 30)
     ) T2(ID_staging_lane, pallet_capacity)
```

Expected result:

```
|-----------|--------|--------------------|---------------|------------------|
|T1_sequence|T1_store|T1_pallet_estimation|T2_staging_lane|T2_pallet_capacity|
|-----------|--------|--------------------|---------------|------------------|
| 1         | A      | 35                 | 201           | 10               |
| 1         | A      | 35                 | 202           | 10               |
| 1         | A      | 35                 | 204           | 30               |
| 2         | C      |  2                 | 205           | 40               |
| 3         | B      | 30                 | 208           | 30               |
|-----------|--------|--------------------|---------------|------------------|
```

Thanks you, Charles, for you time.
I'll try to improve my demand.

If needed, I want to split/divide the pallet_estimation on several staging lanes, following the sequence

Example:

```
For store A which has 35 pallets, 
I want to use staging lane 201 then it remains 35 - 10 = 25 , 
then I want to use staging lane 202 then it remains 25 - 10 = 15, 
then I want to use staging lane 204 then it remains 15 - 30 = -15

then I want to continue with the store C on the next staging lane 205 then it remains 2 - 40 = -38

then I want to continue with the store B on the next staging lane 208 then it remains 30 - 30 = 0
```

How would you start to build that ?
 - with window function ? SUM() OVER()
 - with recursive SQL ? DECLARE FETCH
 - is it possible to build a dynamic JOIN in SQL ?
 - other idea ?

Thanks in advance,

Renaud

Answer (score 1):

First of all, v7r1 is very old...10 years to be exact...

Secondly, I don't understand what you're trying to join on...I see nothing that would explain why store A ended up with 3 rows in your results.

Thirdly, there's no such thing as a "dynamic join", in any RDBMS.  You can have a dyanmic statement, which could include a join.  Or you can have a static statement, which also could include a join.  For Db2 on the IBM i, it only matters if your incorporating the statement in an RPG/COLBOL program or an SQL stored procedure/function.

Now having said all that, let me introduce you to Common Table Expressions (CTE).  Basicaly the same as a Nested Table Expression (NTE) but IMO easier to follow and CTEs also can have a performance benefit over NTE on the i.

```
with T1 as (
  SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES (1, 'A', 35), (2, 'C', 2), (3, 'B', 30)
          ) T1(ID, store, pallet_estimation)
), T2 as (
SELECT * FROM(
  VALUES (201, 10), (202, 10), (204, 30), (205, 40), (208, 30), (210, 30)
     ) T2(ID_staging_lane, pallet_capacity)
), fitment as (
select T1.*, T2.*, row_number() OVER(partition by ID_STAGING_LANE) as rowNbr
from T1 join T2 on pallet_estimation <= pallet_capacity
)
select * from fitment where rowNbr = 1;
```

The `with T1 as (<select statement>)` is the common table expression; as is `T2` and `fitment`.  The `with` keyword is only used for the First CTE.

The `fitment` CTE joins T1 and T2 based upon which estimate fits in the lane description, assigning a row_number to each possibility.  The final select takes the first fit for each lane.

The nice thing about CTE's is you can easily build them and see the results as you go along.  At any point you can add `select * from MYCTE` and see what you have so far.

Note that as shown, a CTE can reference another CTE.  (`fitment` reference both `T1` and `T2`)

**EDIT**
The functions your need to use, to look forward or backwards in the result set are named `LAG()` and `LEAD()`.  They are part of the [OLAP functionality](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzolapexp.htm) built into Db2 for i.  Unfortunately for you, they were added at 7.3.

You will need to roll your own version using a user defined function (UDF) that makes use what's known as the `scatchpad` to save data between the calls to the function for each row.

I found an very old article [Scribble on SQL's Scratchpad](https://web.archive.org/web/20030507181558/http://www.midrangeserver.com/mpo/mpo042403-story02.html) showing how to the scratch pad in RPG.  You can also use it inside an SQL defined UDF.

Do a bit a googling to see if you can get started.  If you run into issues, create a new question here.  (or check out the [Midrange mailing lists](http://www.midrange.com/#lists)

Comment: Hello Charles, 
Thanks for you time.